# Do there exist integers s and t such that 11s + 9t = 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Do there exist integers s and t such that 11s + 9t = 1?

We just started learning discrete mathematics and I am absolutely stuck with proof questions. Does this question belongs to number theory problems? I have no idea how to tackle this kind of questions, not even sure how to start proving it.

Comment: Yes, there exists infinitely many integers which satisfy the  given equation. They are :$$s = 9 n + 5,\quad   t = -11n - 6,\quad   n \in \mathbb Z$$

Comment: I managed to do to a point where proving -(11s+1)/9=t, where s and t are any integers. And by finding a number x which x mod 9 =1, i found the number 55. But does this count as a proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$11s+9t=1\iff9~(s+t)+2s=1\iff2~\Big[4~(s+t)+s\Big]+(s+t)=1=2\cdot0+1=>$

$5s+4t=0$ and $s+t=1\iff s=-4$ and $t=5=>$ all numbers fo the form $s_k=s+9k$

and $t_k=t-11k$ with $k\in$ **Z** are solutions.

Comment: Your one is the clearest and most easy one to understand, without the need of using modulus. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the first few multiples of 11, and the first few multiples of 9, until you find two that are right next to each other.  Then s comes from the multiple of 11, and -t from the multiple of 9.

Comment: I don't know why this got a downvote; I think it's a great answer.

Comment: $44$ and $45$ spring to mind.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer: yes. 11 and 9 do not share any divisor so there exist integers $s$ and $t$ to match any right hand side number ;-)

1 is only the first one you need to make sure of. in the general case it will be the greatest common divisor of the numbers that defines all the reachable numbers. The way to go could be by applying some form of Euclidian algorithm: subtract the smaller $x$ from the larger $y$, then take this result $z$ and the smaller number $x$ as new numbers $x,z$. Think of some form of multiplication with integers $s,t$ to achieve the same! Apply the previous steps indefinitely until you reach the greatest common divisor :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it's a theorem that if $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$ (the greatest common divisor) divides $c$ then there are integers $s$ and $t$ such that $a s + b t = c$. You can find all such integers as follows: firstly note you've got a particular solution $s_0 = -4$, $t_0 = 5$. Suppose that $s,t$ are also integers satisfying $11 s + 9 t = 1$. If you subtract the equations, you find $11 (s-s_0) = 9 (t_0 - t)$. Since the greatest common divisor of $11$ and $9$ is $1$, you must have $s-s_0$ divides 9 and $t_0 - t$ divides 11.

Therefore your general solution is $s = 9 k + s_0$ and $t = 11 k + t_0$ where $k$ can take any value in the integers. You can check that any integers of the form $s = 9 k -4$, $t = 11 k + 5 $ satisfy the above equation.

Answer (score 0):

The existence of $s$ and $t$ is guaranteed by [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

You can also play around with modular arithmetic to find integers solutions that solve $11s+9t=1$. All that is needed is that $11s-1$ is divisible by $9$. As $11\equiv 2(\text{mod }9)$ and $2\times 5-1=9\equiv 0(\text{mod 9})$, solutions involving $s=9x+5$ work for integers $x$. In this case,
$$
9t=1-11s=1-11(9x+5)=-54-99x\implies t=-6-11x.
$$